# JavaFX TableColumn: is there a way to generate a column header event?

Tags: javafx, tablecolumn

I solved the basic problem I was looking at by setting a comparator on the entire table, but what I was initially trying to do was find a way to "click" the header to generate the sorting event.

I'd still like to know how to do this, as I currently do not know of a method to proc sorting methods of the columns, only the table itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`getSortOrder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getSortOrder--) on the `TableView`: that returns a list of `TableColumn`s representing the order by which rows are sorted:

> An empty sortOrder list means that no sorting is being applied on the
>   TableView. If the sortOrder list has one TableColumn within it, the
>   TableView will be sorted using the sortType and comparator properties
>   of this TableColumn (assuming TableColumn.sortable is true). If the
>   sortOrder list contains multiple TableColumn instances, then the
>   TableView is firstly sorted based on the properties of the first
>   TableColumn. If two elements are considered equal, then the second
>   TableColumn in the list is used to determine ordering. This repeats
>   until the results from all TableColumn comparators are considered, if
>   necessary.

Then just add to, remove from, set, clear, etc the list as you need.

SSCCE:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewProgrammaticSort extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = column("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty);
        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = column("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty);
        TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = column("Email", Person::emailProperty);

        table.getColumns().add(firstNameCol);
        table.getColumns().add(lastNameCol);
        table.getColumns().add(emailCol);

        table.getItems().addAll(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );

        ComboBox<TableColumn<Person, ?>> sortCombo = new ComboBox<>();
        sortCombo.getItems().add(firstNameCol);
        sortCombo.getItems().add(lastNameCol);
        sortCombo.getItems().add(emailCol);

        sortCombo.setCellFactory(lv -> new ColumnListCell());
        sortCombo.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldColumn, newColumn) -> {
            table.getSortOrder().clear();
            if (newColumn != null) {
                table.getSortOrder().add(newColumn);
            }
        });
        sortCombo.setButtonCell(new ColumnListCell());

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, sortCombo, null, null, null);
        BorderPane.setMargin(table, new Insets(10));
        BorderPane.setMargin(sortCombo, new Insets(10));
        BorderPane.setAlignment(sortCombo, Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static class ColumnListCell extends ListCell<TableColumn<Person, ?>> {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(TableColumn<Person, ?> column, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(column, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(column.getText());
            }
        }
    }

    private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName");
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName");
        private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "email");

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            this.firstName.set(firstName);
            this.lastName.set(lastName);
            this.email.set(email);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFirstName(final java.lang.String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLastName(final java.lang.String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }

        public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getEmail() {
            return this.emailProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setEmail(final java.lang.String email) {
            this.emailProperty().set(email);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I'm missing a step.  I'm getting that the sortOrder is a list of TableColumns, in order of sort, but how do I generate the sort from a list of TableColumns?

Comment: I don't understand the question in that comment.

Comment: Your answer indicates how to get the sort order of the tableview, not how to cause a sort to happen.  As I understand it.

Comment: You have the list that defines the sort. Just set the items in the list to the columns you want to sort by. `table.getSortOrder().setAll(firstNameCol);` will sort by first name, etc.

Comment: Does this require a followup sort() to then act on the list?

Comment: No? Why would it? See example in updated answer (the listener on the combo box is doing the work).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84829/discussion-between-captain-prinny-and-james-d).